# Chrome custom tabs not opening other apps

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

The `Chrome custom tabs` doesn't seem to launch other apps by deeplinking.

For example a PayPal payment, when `Chrome` is launched with this URL. It will ask the user if the URL has to be opened with the PayPal app or with Chrome.

But this is not the case with `Chrome custom tabs`.

If I use an custom scheme(`myapp://deeplinkurl/`) it works correctly.

How can I allow to let apps override the http scheme?

Comment: Ion, are you asking about links inside a webpage or links you open with a custom tab?

Comment: Links inside the loaded webpage, the users gets a page with multiple payment options. If PayPal is selected, it doesn't open de PayPal app. The Chrome browser itself does.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Custom Chrome Tabs just support custom schemes, http/https won't be launched as a application intent.