# Chrome custom tabs activity result

Tags: android, android-activity, onactivityresult, chrome-custom-tabs, android-customtabs

I'm launching Chrome Custom Tabs using a similar function as below  but I'm always getting the activity result as canceled which makes sense when clicking the close icon. but isn't really helping when I want to differentiate between a redirection to the app and the close icon click. is there a way to set the activity result for the custom tabs?

```
   fun launchURL(context: Context, url: String, requestCode: Int) {
       val builder = CustomTabsIntent.Builder()
       val customTabsIntent = builder.build()
       customTabsIntent.intent.data = Uri.parse(url)
       (context as Activity).startActivityForResult(customTabsIntent.intent, requestCode)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "redirection to the app"? Are you referring to handling deeplink in custom tab?

Comment: @Jakoss yes. I just found CustomTabsCallback, but I thought there would be a way to set the onActivityResult result in a different way than using the callback

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you cannot listen for specific url running in custom tab, so the only way you can handle the redirection to the app is to handle a deeplink. When user clicks the deeplink in the custom tab it will be treated like a normal deeplink in the system. If your app is registered to handle it - it will.

Comment: [I found here info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34859497/chrome-custom-tabs-not-opening-other-apps), which says: 

"Custom Chrome Tabs just support custom schemes, http/https won't be launched as an application intent."

Is that true? Is there really no chance to use http/s url?

Comment: well, it seems like an odd choice there for google, but if they say so - you probably don't have any other options. Honesly, chrome tabs are for basic scenarios. You probably just need to go with WebView