# Open certain links from Chrome custom tabs in Android app?

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs, android-customtabs

I am working on a flow which opens a URL in custom tabs, and after some action navigates to a URL which should deeplink back to the app. When using system browser instead of custom tabs, we are redirected back to app successfully. However when using custom tabs, the URL is still opened within custom tabs. How can I make sure it opens in-app instead?

Comment: I'm afraid [here is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34859497/chrome-custom-tabs-not-opening-other-apps) to your question, where it says: 

"Custom Chrome Tabs just support custom schemes, http/https won't be launched as an application intent."

I'm also looking for the solution

Comment: Maybe this [blog](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/13/android-code-sample-overview/) could help